# Is this result about the defining ideal true?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to generalize a result whose precise statement is the following:

> Let $X$ denote a set of $d+1$ points of $\mathbb P^{d}$ and the points are in linearly general position. Then $I_X$, the defining ideal of $X$, can not be generated by $d$ elements.

I think the result is true but don't see a proper argument to prove this. Any ideas about proof or counterexample?

Comment: You need to say "in linearly general position" rather than "non-colinear". (Otherwise 4 points in a plane in $\mathbf P^3$ is a counterexample.) With that change, the statement is true. Hint for proof: if $I_X$ is cut out by $d$ elements, then $X$ is a complete intersection, so its degree is calculated by Bezout.